# Overriding parent css after using appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have seen several posts suggesting tagging `!important` in css styling in order to override the parent's css. But I have this situation: a child node is created using `document.createElement` and then `appendChild` to the parent:

```
let parentNode = document.getElementById('parentId')
let childNode = document.createElement('div')
childNode.id = 'childId'
parentNode.appendChild(childNode)


#parentId {
  background-color: #6d7373;
  width: 99%;
  height: 40px;
}

#childId {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 99%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

In this case, `!important` does not seem to work. The parent's css is still dominant. Is there any way to make the override? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried giving your child a class unique from the parent and styling that?

Comment: @Jacob I give the child a unique id and style it using that id (background-color). But it does not override.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fgqtnzb7/ <= appears to work as intended

Comment: @Taplar It does not work in my Electron. Background is gray in color. I can see it works in the fiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Set an id for the child element with `Element.setAttribute()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

```js
let parentNode = document.getElementById('parentId')
let childNode = document.createElement('div')
childNode.innerText = 'inner text'
childNode.setAttribute('id', 'childId')
parentNode.appendChild(childNode)
```

```css
#parentId{
  color: red
}

#childId{
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div id='parentId'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I could use the child ID instead of the direct ```>div``` ? I have added more details in my question.

Comment: Thanks. This is the same as Taplar's solution. Somehow it does not work in my Electron app. I am closing this anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @TristanTran sorry to hear that. Have you tried `childNode.id = 'childId'` instead of `setAttribute()`? If not, you can open a new question and specify it's for Electron.